# Is there any way to disable a variation label without deleting it?

Tags: variations

I want to disable a variation label (temporarily) which hierarchy was already created.

Deleting the variation label is another option, but i am not sure that i will easily be able to make the variation label available again later. I mean using the existing hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

well, as a matter of fact, a colleague suggested that what i'm looking for is

```
http://[rootsite]/_layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx
```

and indeed it was. i bypassed the variation selection page and set directly my default variation label welcome page, and that did the trick.